# Microservices: Connection status to external services?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, diagnostics

I've started a new project, and am building my first micro(ish) service. It has a `/health` endpoint, which currently just replies with HTTP status `200` and a `{ "status": "OK" }` body. My service relies on several other (external) services, and I was wondering if there's a standard I can follow for exposing information about the connection between my services and the external ones? I'd like to not invent my own patterns here if there are industry best practices or standards I can follow.

Something like:

```
{
  status: 'OK',
  services: [
    { name: 'kafka', status: 'OK' },
    { name: 'twilio', status: 'OK' }
  ]
}
```

My service will be running in Kubernetes on GCP, if that helps. We use Datadog for observability.

Comment: Are you asking for a pattern of exposing dependencies about your system? Or are you asking about a pattern for what your health check should actually be checking?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear; i'm asking for a pattern for exposing the _status_ of our dependencies. These are not all necessarily things that run in our infrastructure (e.g., Twilio, Salesforce)

Comment: Hope you will be having corresponding status code if the dependencies are not available. In that case logging the details is one of the option. Looks like this document will give a different approach https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services